# Which is suitable for car detection, CascadeClassifier or HOGDescriptor?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

My goal is to detect cars in images and recognize its model. For car-detection, from http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/opencv_cheatsheet.pdf, it says:

> CascadeClassifier
>
> Viola’s Cascade of Boosted classifiers us-ing Haar or LBP features.
>   Suits for de-tecting faces, facial features and some other objects
>   without diverse textures. See facedetect.cpp
>
> HOGDescriptor
>
> N. Dalal’s object detector using Histogram-of-Oriented-Gradients (HOG)
>   features. Suits for detect-ing people, cars and other objects with
>   well-defined silhouettes. See peopledetect.cpp

and from http://docs.opencv.org/opencv2refman.pdf , chapter 8.1 Cascade Classification ,page 421:

> First, a classifier (namely a cascade of boosted classifiers working
>   with haar-like features) is trained with a few hundred sample views of
>   a particular object (i.e., a face or a car), called positive examples,
>   that are scaled to the same size (say, 20x20), and negative examples -
>   arbitrary images of the same size.

Both of these two methods mention about applying for car detection: in opencv_cheatsheet.pdf it says HOGDescriptor suits for cars and in opencv2refman.pdf it also mentions cars for Cascade Classification. So my question is how to choose between CascadeClassifier and HOGDescriptor, and which is better for car detection? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any HOG descriptor for detecting cars in OpenCV?

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to tell without testing, but actually I got very good results with a third option - latentSVM detector.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Which dataset did you use to train the classifier? Is it possible to share that?

Comment: I used OpenCV's pretrained models

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think there is a pre-trained model  available for vehicle detection in OpenCV for latentSVM. Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: Here:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/tree/master/testdata/cv/latentsvmdetector/models_VOC2007

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goals in terms of speed, accuracy etc. You use cascade classifiers and can get the desired results. Although cascade classifiers are quite good but still they are computational expensive. In that case you can you gpu. Below is an few example for you.

https://github.com/abhi-kumar/CAR-DETECTION

Answer (score 0):

It's a research question. Classifier trained by and CascadeClassifier and HOG can be used to detect vehicles. OpenCV provide a detailed help to build a customized detector in case of CascadeClassifier and HOG. Quality of the classifier can be described by accuracy and in my case I was more interested in real time implementation. So you have to look a number of different factors.